# Add two turtlebot in one .world

Tags: roslaunch, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am a freshman on ROS and I meet a problem: I write a very simple .py for one turtlebot to move straight, after I add another turtlebot in the world, the original one cannot move, it used to move automatically. I really do not know the reason.
In my launch file, I have not added the node of the second one.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283021/add-two-turtlebot-in-one-.world/) by [YIC](https://answers.ros.org/users/33744/yic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should take a look at this [answer about setting up multiple robots in Gazebo](https://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/?answer=41434#post-id-41434). Don't worry about when the answer was made or that it's probably not the correct version of ROS. Much of it is still applicable.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [YIC](https://answers.ros.org/users/33744/yic/) on 2018-02-19**:
Thank you, I have fixed the problem. That is because I did not change the publisher information in the code. After I add a new robot, the rostopic list has changed and original robot is changed from "cmd_vel" to "robot_0/cmd_vel"